# Obtaining function from integrals

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I have a question I cannot figure out if it's correct or not.
I have a function $f(x,y)$ unknown which I'd like to obtain.
Starting from $q(y) = \int dxf(x,y)$ and $g(x) = \int dyf(x,y)$ I think I should be able to extract $f(x,y)$. Do you have any suggestion? 
Many thanks

Comment: I am afraid this problem lacks of uniqueness...

Comment: You should clarify your notation - i.e., what is "$q(y) = \int dx f(x,y)$"?

Comment: what is lacking my notation? I cannot understand

Comment: What do you mean by "$q(y) = \int dx f(x,y)$"? Do you perhaps mean that you fix $y$ and then obtain a (family of) primitives of $f( \cdot, y)$?

Comment: yes is exactly what I meant, thank you

Comment: In this case, in general $\int dx f(x,y)$ will depend on $x$. For example, consider $f(x,y) = x^2+xy$. Then by fixing $y$, we get that a primitive of $f(\cdot,y)$ is $q(x,y) = \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^2y}{2}$ (you can check that by computing $\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}$).

Comment: ok I got the misunderstanding: $q(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dx$

Comment: Then I suppose what @Brethlosze said is right: a function of the form $f(x,y) + h(x,y)$ where $h(x,y)$ is odd in both $x$ and $y$ (i.e. $h(-x,y) = -h(x,y)$ and $h(x,-y) = -h(x,y)$) should produce the same $q$ and $g$ as $f$.

Comment: I am positive this kind of problems could have an unique solution ensured (how?) under some conditions (which ones?)